# Set-AzDataFactoryV2 Invalid parameter

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-data-factory

I want to create a datafactory and link it to an azure devops repository with the command line Set-AzDataFactoryV2.

So I installed the following module: **Az.DataFactory** (1.8.2)

As the microsoft documentation mentionned it ([click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/Set-AzDataFactoryV2?view=azps-4.3.0)), it should possible with the following commands:

```
Get-AzDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName "ADF" -Name "WikiADF" | Set-AzDataFactoryV2 -AccountName msdata -RepositoryName ADFRepo -CollaborationBranch master -RootFolder / -ProjectName "Azure Data Factory"
```

OR

```
New-AzDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName "ADF" -Name "WikiADF" -Location 'EastUS' -HostName 'https://github.com' -AccountName msdata -RepositoryName ADFRepo -CollaborationBranch master -RootFolder /
```

But the result is

```
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument : (:) [Set-AzDataFactoryV2], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactoryV2.SetAzureDataFactoryCommand
```

What is the problem ?
Is it possible to create a datafactory and link it to a repository with a command line with other ways (without API REST) ?

Comment: Do you have a chance to look into my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the two commands you shared in this post with module: Az.DataFactory (1.8.2) and both of them work fine. I only modify the resource group name and data factory name.

Based on the error message you provided, it means one the the parameters is invalid.

For example, if I modify the parameter `-Name` to `-Namettt`:

```
New-AzDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName "ADF" -Namettt "WikiADF" -Location 'EastUS' -HostName 'https://github.com' -AccountName msdata -RepositoryName ADFRepo -CollaborationBranch master -RootFolder /
```

I will get the same error as yours.

Please check if you have all the parameters corrected.